# IOS removes allocated memory in native library

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, c, memory-management

Strange behavior in IOS while integrating with a c/c++ library.

In AppDelegate i call

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND,0), ^{
    [[ABCService sharedInstance] abcInitialize];
});
```

abcInitialize is defined in c++ library

```
struct abc *top;
top = calloc(TYPE_SERV,size_of(struct abc));
top->us = server_alloc (...certain_params...);
```

inside server alloc i do alloc of structures **struct1** and **struct2**
And then in Initialize function i try to access

```
top->us = calloc(TYPE_US, size_of(struct us));
if(top->us->struct1) //do something
```

I noticed that my struct1 is always null

When i debugged, i can see that the structure was allocated fine and values are set appropriately, but before returning from the function, the memory is automatically deallocated.
This is totally confusing and annoying. 
Could any one help me understand what is going on?

**I tried by turning off ARC too, still no change**

Comment: You need to show how struct1 is allocated and how it is declared.

Comment: stuct1 is being allocated as calloc (1, stuct1_size);

Comment: I guess you need to show how abcInitialize: is looks like. Because in your current code you don't allocate memory for `top` pointer but assign something to `us` member (top->us = ...).

Comment: You never allocated `top`.

Comment: (You need to show some actual code.)

Comment: Edited the code. The native code is completely working on linux and android. So nothing to be changed in the native code. I woud like to know the memory configuration for IOS in such situations

Comment: Is abcInitialize code objc? Also c code is unmanaged. Most probably the allocations are valid only in the scope of the dispatch block. Could it be a weak refernence causing that?

Comment: @blganesh101 please provide more code

Answer (score 7):

> ```
> top->us = calloc(TYPE_US, size_of(struct us));
> if(top->us->struct1) //do something
> ```
>
> I noticed that my struct1 is always null

If that's your real code, then yes, `struct1` will always be null. `calloc` allocates memory and initializes it to zero. Hence, *all* of the members of `top->us` will be zero, and since `struct1` is a member of `top->us`, it's going to be zero, i.e. `NULL`.

Comment: struct1 is allocated. This is not the real code. The real code works on all platforms and no changes done for IOS

Answer (score 4):

First of all, ARC has nothing to do with memory management of C or C++ codes, so, you can rule out ARC for causing this.

According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/calloc/, calloc always initialize all the bits of the allocated memory to 0, naturally, top->us->struct1 will be NULL.

> but before returning from the function, the memory is automatically
>   deallocated

How do you come to the conclusion that the memory is automatically deallocated? As mentioned above, ARC will not automatically release your C++ structure/object.

As a conclusion. The result you saw was indeed as expected.

Comment: When i debugged, the memory is allocated fine and i could see the structure values intact., Upon function return the same structure is de-allocated. I am wondering why is this strange behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and it was due to linking the same file twice from different library. I have corrected my libraries and that had fixed my issue. So no source code was updated. Just the libs were corrected with the right sources. 
Thanks a lot of for your support.